show that $\|\partial_v u\|_{H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega)} \leq C\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$
$\partial_v u$ means conormal derivative of $u$.
Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ be a solution for a problem $Lu = F$ in $\Omega$ and $u = g$ on $\partial\Omega$, where $L$ is an elliptic operator.
Then i want to show that $\|\partial_v u\|_{H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega)} \leq C\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$, but i was able to show $$\|\partial_v u\|_{H^{-1/2}(\partial\Omega)} \leq C(\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)} + \|F-cu\|_{L^2(\Omega)}),$$ where $\|c\|_{L^\infty} \leq M$. Is there a way to get rid of the $ \|F-cu\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ somehow?

Maybe you can estimate $|u|{H^1}$ against $|F|{L^2}$ and an appropriate norm of $g$?

there is a result which says that $|u|{H^1(\Omega)} \leq C(|F|{L^2(\Omega)} + |g|{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)})$, but that doesnt really help, if it were vice versa it would solve my problem, namely $C|u|{H^1(\Omega)} \geq |F|{L^2(\Omega)} + |g|{H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)}$

you would need to apply triangle inequality like $|F+cu| \le |F| + |c|\cdot |u|$ with the correct norms ofc.

sure, but need an estimate for $|F|_{L^2(\Omega)}$

It is not possible to get rid of this second term. If this would be the case, you would be able to define a normal derivative for all functions in $H^1(\Omega)$. However, this is not possible: Since functions from $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ have a zero normal derivative, all functions from $H_0^1(\Omega)$ also would have a zero normal derivative (density), but this is absurd.
